# Ignore some properties when transfering an object from the WCF service to the client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a poco on the service side of my application.   I want to transfer this object to the client but WITHOUT some specific properties.

Is there a way to "hide" some properties when returning the result to my client?

I already tried   [IgnoreDataMember] , [IgnoreProperties("xxx")] , [NonSerialized] and many other attributes without luck... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: share your code please

Comment: What do you have on service side Soap/Rest?

Comment: @michelqa What do you mean by Ignore? Do you mean you want to completely take them out from the Soap Message reply or simply emit default values of ignored properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF service must be using a `DataContract` on the poco class, remove `[DataMember]` attribute from the properties and that should work.

For example, below `BoolValue` will not be part of the contract.

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    //Not a part of contract
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I need!